# Idempotent Laurent polynomials (in noncommuting variables)

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, polynomials, noncommutative-rings, laurent-polynomials

Let $K$ be a field and $R=K\langle X_1,\dots,X_n,X_1^{-1},\dots,X_n^{-1}\rangle$ the Laurent polynomial ring in $n$ noncommuting variables. Can $R$ have idempotents distinct from $0$ and $1$?

Answer (score 7):

No, it can not. $R$ is a group ring of the free group with $n$ generators. This group is locally indicable (any non-trivial subgroup has a homomorphism onto $\mathbb{Z}$), thus by result of Higman (Higman G. The Units of Group Rings // Proc. London Math. Soc. 1940. Vol. 46. P. 231–248) it satisfies the Kaplansky zero divisors conjecture: its group ring over a field does not have zero divisors (in particular, it does not contain non-trivial idempotents).

Comment: I think it was known that free groups are left orderable since Magnus before it was known that locally indicable implies left orderable, such was Burns.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg I am not an expert in history of algebra at all, but Hidman talks a lot about free groups and seems to pretend to be the first to prove Kaplansky conjecture for free groups.

Comment: The argument being straightforward for locally indicable groups (for convenience I included it [in an answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/381387/14094), it's unnecessary to to go through left-orderability. Maybe the latter is useful to prove the non-existence of zero divisors at all.

Comment: (of course, Higman's paper preceeds Kaplansky conjecture, so he does not use such words)

Comment: Yes.  But I had thought Higman went through orderability but I dont remember

Comment: You are right Higman did use indicability and did it to get no zero divisors

Answer (score 6):

Here's a self-contained proof (which is certainly Higman's proof), following Fedor Petrov's answer.

Let $G$ be a locally indicable group (= every nontrivial f.g. subgroup has $\mathbf{Z}$ as quotient). The $KG$ has no nontrivial idempotent.

Indeed, suppose $u^2=u$ in $KG$ with $u\neq 0,1$. Then passing to the subgroup generated by $\mathrm{Supp}(u)$, we can suppose that the support of $u$ generates $G$, and that $G$ is finitely generated. Clearly $G\neq 1$. Then fix a surjective homomorphism $G\to\mathbf{Z}$. Push forward $u$ to $K[\mathbf{Z}]$ to get an idempotent, whose support generates $\mathbf{Z}$. But $K[\mathbf{Z}]=K[t^{\pm 1}]$ has no nontrivial idempotent, contradiction.

Comment: Your "no zero divisor" should read as "no non-trivial idempotent", or the proof must be modified.

Comment: @FedorPetrov typo is fixed, thanks

Comment: Yes this is Higman's proof except he does the obvious modification for zero divisors.  I had thought he had used ordering but I guess not

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg what is the obvious modification for zero divisors? If $uv=0$, we may suppose that the supports of $u$ and $v$ generate $G$, then there exists a homomorphism $G\to \mathbb{Z}$ which is non-zero either on $u$ or on $v$, but why on both?

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg I'm also not sure what you mean by obvious modification, as the homomorphism from the group generated by $\mathrm{Supp}(u)\cup\mathrm{Supp}(v)$ onto $\mathbf{Z}$ might kill $\mathrm{Supp}(v)$.

Comment: Look at Higman's paper.  It is on page 242.  He does an extremely similar argument.  He doesn't quite push into laurent polynomials. He uses the indexing function to imitate the proof for Laurent polynomials

Comment: Thank you all for your answers!

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg What if one replaces the free group $G$ by a groupoid obtained from a free group by "forbidding" some products? Can the groupoid algebra have nontrivial idempotents?

Comment: @Ralle, What do you mean by groupoid? To me that means a category where all morphisms are invertible.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg I am using the algebraic definition from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupoid.

Comment: @Ralle, then what do you mean by forbidding some products?  Anyway groupoid algebras are direct sums of matrix algebras over groups and so will always have non-trivial idempotents unless they are groups.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg What I meant is that one takes a free group and declares some products in this group as not defined (in such a way that one gets a groupoid). More formally: Let $G$ be a free group with composition $\circ$. Let $S$ be a subset of $G\times G$ containing all pairs $(g,g^{-1})$ where $g\in G$. Let $\ast$ be the restriction of $\circ$ to $S$. Then $(G,^{-1},\ast)$ is a groupoid .

Comment: @Ralle, this doesn't seem a groupoid to me.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Sorry, I withdraw my question!